# Check if Index value is > 1 of XElement attribute value

Tags: c#

I have a variable that gets all the values of my xml and I would like to check to see if the index of it is greater than 1.

Here is my variable

```
var IdList = xmlElements.Attributes("value");
```

Which will have values in it that look like this:

```
[0] = {value="akjldshfkjsdhf"}
[1] = {value="wefjafvkjashfk"}
```

I basically wanna check if the index value will be greater than one. But i am unsure how.

so `if the index has more than 1 ID do this`

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: The index of what? It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. You may well find that you don't need the index, so much as to skip the first two attributes before trying to find a particular one...

Comment: I would like to check if the value returns more than one index. so if the variable has more than one id in it do... Does that make more sense?

Comment: So you're after the *count*? That's easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after the *count* of the `value` elements, you can just use:

```
var count = IdList.Count();
if (count > 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Or if you don't need the count afterwards, you can just see whether there are any left after you've skipped one:

```
if (IdList.Skip(1).Any())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: That would be exactly what I need. Wow very simple. Thanks for the help. I will mark you as the answer when SO lets me.